# MySQL Count all rows and unique rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do exactly what the title says, get the total number of records and the number of records that are unique in a certain column.

What I tried so far

```
SELECT COUNT(ip) AS visits, ip FROM tracker WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY ip

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(ip) AS visits, ip FROM tracker WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ?

SELECT DCOUNT(ip) AS visits, DISTINCT(ip) AS `unique` FROM tracker WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

However none of these brought me pleasant feelings.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you need is this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT)
```

So it should be :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS visits FROM tracker;
```

Comment: Now I'm left to wonder if this is efficient or not `:D`. Thanks!

Comment: I have to say that I'm wondering the same. But I've to add that a where statement will help you to increase the performance if we talk about a specific period of time.